# Spring MVC: processing values from timesheet - multiple objects

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I'm working on a timesheet/actiontracker application. I'm using Spring MVC. This is my current situation:

I got a form with all the tasks. Next to these tasks there are seven textboxes (which display the amount of hours for the next seven days). A user must be able to save the tasks (and the hours). I'm not really sure how to send these results to the controller. It contains a list of objects.
Let's say...

```
TaskID - Taskname - D1 - D2 - D3 ...
1        Hello      5    3    2
2        Bai        4    2    1
3        I'm back   3    4    3
```

It should send a list of task objects back, so I can insert/update/delete a timerecord.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, hope this helps!

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

    private Timesheet timesheet;

    public ExampleController() {
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        tasks.add(new Task(1, "Hello", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        tasks.add(new Task(2, "Bai", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        tasks.add(new Task(3, "I'm back", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.timesheet = new Timesheet(tasks);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/timesheet.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayTimeSheet() {
        return new ModelAndView("timesheet", "timesheet", timesheet);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/timesheet.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateTimeSheet(@ModelAttribute("timesheet") Timesheet timesheet) {
        this.timesheet = timesheet;
        return new ModelAndView("timesheet", "timesheet", timesheet);
    }

}
```

**JSP Page**

```
<form:form commandName="timesheet">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>TaskID</th>
      <th>Taskname</th>
      <th>D1</th>
      <th>D2</th>
      <th>D3</th>
      <th>D4</th>
      <th>D5</th>
      <th>D6</th>
      <th>D7</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${timesheet.tasks}" var="task" varStatus="tasksRow">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <form:hidden path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].id"/>
          <c:out value="${timesheet.tasks[tasksRow.index].id}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:hidden path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].name"/>
          <c:out value="${timesheet.tasks[tasksRow.index].name}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day1hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day2hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day3hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day4hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day5hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day6hours"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="tasks[${tasksRow.index}].day7hours"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

**Model Classes**

```
public class Timesheet {

    private List<Task> tasks;

public class Task {

    private int    id;
    private String name;
    private int    day1hours;
    private int    day2hours;
    private int    day3hours;
    private int    day4hours;
    private int    day5hours;
    private int    day6hours;
    private int    day7hours;
```

You can download the entire example project here:

http://www.bitsandbytecode.com/ftp/spring-mvc-multi-record-form.zip

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I got some problems with my controller now, but the main problem got fixed. What would be the best way to "check" if I actually receive the information? I will have to loop through the timesheet/TaskList. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot for the effort though. Appreciate it.

Comment: The error I get btw:
[23/03/11 15:06:02:099 CET] 00000026 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[actiontracker]: org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'tasks[0]' of bean class [be.pv.actiontracker.domain.TaskList]: Cannot access indexed value of property referenced in indexed property path 'tasks[0]': returned null

Comment: I added a link to the entire project above so that you can download it to see if there is anything different from what you are doing. I didn't encounter any problems in the controller when I was trying this out myself. As far as the error you are getting, it appears that either the tasks collection is null, or the element at the index of 0 is null.

Comment: If you use Spring's org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList instead of an ArrayList, you don't need to worry about having created Task objects yourself for your list to handle the posted form.

Comment: Nice GriffeyDog, I'd never AutoPopulatingList before. I found a pretty good explanation about it here: http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=12.

Comment: As pointed out by @Vandana (in a separate, possibly removed by the time you read this, answer), the link for the entire example project (at the bottom of this answer) is broken.